# Can I define a property within an object prototype (method)?

Tags: javascript, oop, properties, processing.js

Question part 1: I've made an object constructor with properties in it, but I am wondering if I could define another property of the object within one of it's methods. For example:

```
var Player = function(p1) {
    this.property1 = p1;
    this.property2 = 0;
}
```

then, can I define `this.property3` in a method, like:

```
Player.prototype.drawMethod = funtion() {
    this.property3 = 1;
}
```

and have it accessible, like:

```
var obj = new Player(true);
if (obj.property3 ===1 && obj.property1 === 1) {
    //code
} else {
    obj.property3 = obj.property2;
}
```

Question part 2: Also, will properties be accepted as functions, and would I call them using the following way:

```
this.func = function() {
    //code
}
...
obj.func();
```

Comment: Object is already defined in javascript.  Are you asking if you can overwrite Object with your version of an Object constructor function?  Or is it just a coincidence you picked the name Object for your function?

Comment: You can add properties to any object, there's nothing special about objects with a constructor.

Comment: I don't think `if (obj.property3 === 1 === obj.property1) {` does what you think it does. It doesn't compare all 3 things with each other, that would be `if(obj.property3 ===1 && obj.property1 === 1)`.

Comment: @user2263572 The name of the constructor was a coincidence, I could've named it `Player`

Comment: @Roman It would best if you edited the question, to avoid confusion.

Comment: The only thing special about properties assigned in the constructor is that all instances created with the constructor will have those properties. Properties added later will only exist in those instances.

Comment: @Barmar I fixed the if statement.

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? `obj.property3 === 1` returns `true/false`, and it will compare that with `obj.property1`.

Comment: @Barmar So there are global/local properties, like global/local variables?

Comment: No, there aren't. They're all local properties. But the property doesn't exist until you add it to the object. If you add it in the contructor, then it's there from the moment the object is created. If you add it somewhere else, then it's there after you call that other function.

Comment: Yes, you can. Just run your code.

Comment: You can have properties that are inherited from a prototype, they're available in all objects created from that prototype.

Comment: That makes no sense. Properties of an object come into existence when you assign to them. `obj = {}`. It has no properties. `obj.bar = 3`. Now it has a property `bar`.

Comment: @Barmar Oh wow. It is valid to say `Player.prototype.drawMethod.prototype.secondMethod = function() {};`

Comment: I think your problem may be assuming that Javascript OO is like C++, where you have to declare all the properties in the class declaration. JS is dynamic, you just add properties to object on the fly.

Comment: The constructor is just a function that initializes a bunch of properties when you first create the object, but that doesn't prevent you from adding more properties later.

Comment: I understand now. Indeed, JavaScript is very dynamic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because all of these questions can be answered by simply running the example code and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering if I could define another property of the object within one of it's methods

Yes you can.

But notice that this is considered bad style, because it's not visible at one single point (the constructor) which properties the instances will have. Also engines are known not to optimise this case - they reserve the necessary space for the shape of object that the constructor creates, and changing this after the instantiation requires some extra work.

> Will properties be accepted as functions, and would I call them [like methods]?

Yes.